# Reading edited UITextFields from custom UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have list of items presented to the user for editing in the form of a tableView. Once the list is edited, I would like to store the edited list back into an array.

I have a loop to read the each item, but it comes up with an empty list of cells.  I assume I am not identifying the indexPath correctly.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
// This establishes the tableView correctly

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:
        IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
   "cell1", for: indexPath) as! a8EditorTableViewCell
    cell.listItem?.text = popChoices[indexPath.row]

    return cell

// Action attempts to save the edited data, but produces 
tChoices = []

@IBAction func save(_ sender: Any) { 
    var tChoices: [String] = []
    //IndexPath.row.forEach {
    let n = popChoices.count // ok
    print("save, n=",n)
    for index in (0...n) {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row:index, section:0)
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:
                "cell1", for: indexPath) as! a8EditorTableViewCell
        tChoices.append(cell.listItem.text!)

        print("n=",n,"tchoice=",cell.listItem.text!) // < prints 
         blanks
    }
    print("tchoices=",tChoices)
    print("popChoices before change=",popChoices)
    popChoices = tChoices
    onChg?(popChoice)  //  need to change to array

    print("popChoiceA=",popChoice)
    dismiss(animated: true)

}
```

Results shown below. Should be 15 strings.

tchoices= ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]

Comment: You don't read the text from the cells, you get the text from your `popChoices` array which is you keep up-to-date as each text field is updated.

Comment: start class names with capital letter `A8EditorTableViewCell `

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `cellForRowAt` instead of `dequeueReusableCell`

```
(0..<n).forEach {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row:$0, section:0)
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at:indexPath) as? A8EditorTableViewCell {
      tChoices.append(cell.listItem.text!)
    }
}
```

OR

```
(tableView.visibleCells as! [A8EditorTableViewCell]).forEach { 
  tChoices.append($0.listItem.text!)
}
```

> This assumes all cells of the table are visible if it's no the case you need to go with another way

Comment: After testing further, I realize now that it only works for visible rows, as you've stated. So there appears to be no way to access the full array when doing multiple edits in a scrolled table?